# How to store ID's in an array while showing the button(s) as pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a doubt of how to store or remove multiples ID's on an array while the button is been pressed.
Also when the button is pressed once it got an animation, showing that is current pressed until it's pressed again.

Maybe it has to deal with DOM manipulation but it's out of my understanding how to do it.

Below my code in HTML, CSS and JS to console log this action:
**OBS: now I only managed to show console log for the first buton.**

```js
var sorteioController = (function() {

  var selecao = function(id, howmany, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.howmany = howmany;
    this.valor = value;
  }
  //select element

  var allItems = {
    selec: []
  }



  //send info

  return {
    addItem: function(id, hm, val) {
      var newItem;

      if (data.allItems[id].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }

      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
      return newItem;
    },
  }
})();

var UIController = (function() {
  return {
    getinput: function() {
      todosItens = document.querySelector('.btn_reservas').toggleAttribute;
    }
  };

})();
var controller = (function(sorteioCtrl, UICtrl) {
  var ctrlAddItem = function() {

    console.log('It worked, pressed id  = ' + this.id);
  }

  document.querySelector('.btn_reservas').addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);

  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
      ctrlAddItem();
    }

  });



})(sorteioController, UIController);
```

```css
.lista ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.lista ul li a {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #bfc0bf;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 75px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgb(85, 161, 108);
  border-color: #212529;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.lista ul li a:hover {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font: bolder;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="00" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">01</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="01" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">02</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="02" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">03</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="03" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">04</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="04" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">05</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only managed to show console log for the first buton.

You should use `querySelectorAll` and loop the event listener. So replace the following:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn_reservas').addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);
```

With a loop this way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn_reservas").forEach(function () {
  this.addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);
});
```

And change the `ctrlAddItem` function this way and also add some class:

```js
var ctrlAddItem = function(e) {
  console.log('It worked, pressed id  = ' + e.target.id);
  e.target.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
var sorteioController = (function() {

  var selecao = function(id, howmany, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.howmany = howmany;
    this.valor = value;
  }
  //select element

  var allItems = {
    selec: []
  }

  //send info

  return {
    addItem: function(id, hm, val) {
      var newItem;

      if (data.allItems[id].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }

      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);
      return newItem;
    },
  }
})();

var UIController = (function() {
  return {
    getinput: function() {
      todosItens = document.querySelector('.btn_reservas').toggleAttribute;
    }
  };

})();

var controller = (function(sorteioCtrl, UICtrl) {
  var ctrlAddItem = function(e) {
    console.log('It worked, pressed id  = ' + e.target.id);
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
  }

  document.querySelectorAll(".btn_reservas").forEach(function () {
    this.addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);
  });
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
      ctrlAddItem();
    }
  });

})(sorteioController, UIController);
```

```css
.lista ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.lista ul li a {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #bfc0bf;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 75px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgb(85, 161, 108);
  border-color: #212529;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.lista ul li a:hover {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font: bolder;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}

.lista ul li a.active {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="00" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">01</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="01" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">02</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="02" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">03</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="03" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">04</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="04" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="test">05</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I get something like this now:

[image: two pressed]